# Get ASP.NET Core API version programmatically in integration test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core with the [ASP.NET API Versioning](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning) service.

When I register the service, I use this format:

```cs
services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(o => o.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV");
```

In an integration test, using the `WebApplicationFactory`:

```cs
var controller = nameof(CustomerController).Replace("Controller", "");
var action = nameof(CustomerController.SignIn);
var version = "v0";                                   // <------- the problem
var route = $"/api/${version}/${controller}/${action}";

var client = _factory.CreateClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(route);
```

I don't want to hardcode `version`. Is it possible to get it from the test server somehow? Perhaps from the version service?

Comment: you need to return the version from the api somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be retrieved from the container like so:

```cs
var version = _factory
  .Services
  .GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>()
  .ApiVersionDescriptions
  .Single()    // if you have multiple versions, choose correct one
  .GroupName;
```